# HTTP GET by sending parametres RETROFIT android

Tags: java, android, get, retrofit, retrofit2

[Postman refernce image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyq3r.png)
When I hit the HTTP GET request by passing the below parameters in body at postman I can able to get the current responce
{
"pickup_postcode":"600114",
"delivery_postcode": "600125",
"cod": "1",
"weight": "1"
}

But when I implement it in retrofit android I am getting null object. I have used @Query to pass the above parameters. I have attached the code below.
Thanks in advance

```
public interface ShipRocketServiceAbilityInterface {
    @GET("courier/serviceability/")
    Call<ShipRocketServiceabilityResponse> getService(
 @Query("pickup_postcode") String pickupPostcode,
 @Query("delivery_postcode") String deliveryPostcode,
 @Query("cod") String cod,
 @Query("weight") String weight);
}
```

```
//API Call

        String pickupPostcode = "600114";
        String deliveryPostcode = "600125";
        boolean cod = "1";
        float weight = "1";
        Call<ShipRocketServiceabilityResponse> service =
        shipRocket.getService(pickupPostcode,deliveryPostcode,cod,weight);
        service.enqueue(new Callback<ShipRocketServiceabilityResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ShipRocketServiceabilityResponse> call, Response<ShipRocketServiceabilityResponse> response) {
                String  dataList = response.body().getCurrency();
              

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ShipRocketServiceabilityResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                Log.d("TAG","FAIL");

            }
        });
```

Comment: I think your ```ShipRocketServiceabilityResponse``` object is not as per the json you are getting in response.

Answer (score 0):

I see many issues in the code provided by you. In-fact, it should not even pass at compile time.

As Shivam pointed out ShipRocketServiceabilityResponse we first need to learn about what the model looks like.

```
public interface ShipRocketServiceAbilityInterface {
    @GET("courier/serviceability/")
    Call<ShipRocketServiceabilityResponse> getService(
    @Query("pickup_postcode") String pickupPostcode,
    @Query("delivery_postcode") String deliveryPostcode,
    @Query("cod") String cod,
    @Query("weight") String weight);
}

// API Call
String pickupPostcode = "600114";
String deliveryPostcode = "600125";
String cod = "1";
String weight = "1";
```

Ideally, this is how we can parse the value right away. might as well run the debugger to see the values coming from GET request.

Hope this helps.